# TComPort acting wierd

Tags: delphi, tcomport

I have a SMS gateway that i control using AT Commands the component works fine but i am not able to parse the strings recieved from the device corectly.

First of all i use hardware Flow Control how that affects me ?

I use the TComDataPacket component witch has an event onPacket() where i recieve a string if i use the debugger i can see the string ok but if i use pos() to search or ShowMessage() to show the string the string is very short and i don't see any #00

I tryied using the RxChar event but is not triggered and RxBuf gives an access violation.

I using Delphi XE 2 is there any thing wrong with the component or i am doing something wrong?

LE : The event onPacket() freezes if i don't insert a sleep at the end of the method here is my code :

```
procedure TfrmMain.comPacketPacket(Sender: TObject; const Str: string);
var
  S,numar,coord : string;
  i,poi,rr,j,tmp2 : Integer;
const
  Readul = 'READ|';
  delim  = 'gps=';
  CMG = 'CMGL';
begin
  if pos('CMTI',Str) > 0 then
                          SendATCommand('AT+CMGL="ALL"');
  for i := 1 to Length(Str) do
    if Str[i] in ['A'..'Z','a'..'z','0'..'9','=','.'] then S := S + Str[i]
    else if Str[i] = '"' then S := S + '|';
    repeat
       poi := Pos('gps=',S);
       if poi > 0 then
       begin
          j := poi;
          repeat
            Dec(j);
            rr := PosEx(Readul,S,j);
            if rr >= poi then  rr := 0;
          until (rr>0) or (j = 1);
          numar := Copy(S,rr+Length(Readul)+1,PosEx('|',S,(rr+Length(Readul)+1)) - (rr + Length(Readul) + 1));
          ShowMessage('Trimit la numarul ' + numar);
          coord := Copy(S,poi + Length(delim),PosEx(CMG,S,poi) - poi - Length(CMG));
          S := Copy(S,poi + Length(delim),Length(S));
       end;
    until poi = 0;
    Sleep(1500);
end;
```

Comment: Which version are you using? There are several competing versions out there. Many versions have serious bugs in the packet component. I sadly and humbly confess that I don't use the packet and thus I have been disgusting about never fixing Packet bugs.  Avoid packet. Do without it. Done.

Comment: @WarrenP the latest version of this component http://sourceforge.net/projects/comport/

Comment: I believe that version still has packet bugs on Unicode delphi.

Comment: @WarrenP is there anything better ?

Comment: can you show here an example string that shows but doesn't work with Pos/ShowMessage?

Comment: I use TComport WITHOUT the packet component.

Comment: @WarrenP and how do you get notified if there is somethin` on the com port ?

Comment: You just read, and you get back the number of characters, if it's zero, you wait a few milliseconds, and try again.  It's a very simple matter of loops and timeouts.  And its much better to do such loops in the background threads than in your VCL thread.  I can see that most serial port developers who are not comfortable with safely writing threads would rather delegate this WaitForPacket thing to a function or component.

Comment: You can also try the different SyncMethods. If the ComPort is not synchronized to the main thread (i.e. the event is not triggered in the main thread), you cannot use ShowMessage: it may freeze, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is string.
In XE2, string is unicode string.
in Delphi 2007 and below, string is ansi string.
Their size is different.
You must make it sure by checking TComport source.